# Visual Studio 2019 "Add Connection" window crashes when trying to add Oracle Database Connection into Server Explorer > Data Connections

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2019, oracle19c, odp.net-managed, odp

I am trying to add Oracle database into Visual Studio 2019 Professional > Server Explorer.

I am able to get to the Add Connection Window after choosing Oracle Database ODP.NET, Managed Driver, however as soon as I choose an option under Connection Type (See image below) such as TNS Alias, the windows crashes without any error.

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShlSc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShlSc.png)]

Environment:

OS: Windows 10

IDE: Visual Studio 2019 Professional

ODT Version: 19.3.3.0

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Oracle Developer Tools and Visual Studio Professional 2019 but the problem is not resolving.

Have also tried to fix the ODT configuration by running the following command but I am getting the error shown in the image:

.\OraVsProvCfgUpdater.exe VS2019Professional 19.3.3.0

[image]